# How to share a directory between windows and virtualbox?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualbox, shared-directory

I recently installed virtualbox 6.1.4 on my windows 10.

I used the image ubuntu-18.04.4-server-amd64 as image.

When I try to share a directory between windows and linux, It doesn't appear on linux virtual machine.

The image of configuration used is below:

[The program is in portuguese, however, the **shared area of transference** and the **drag and drop** are set to biderectional](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIit2.png)

The shared folder path is: C:\Users\my-user-name\VirtualBoxVMs\ubuntu_server\share

Folder name: share. And It is set to automaticaly mounting.

When I try the installed guest additions, this error appears:

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu33z.png)

How can I create a shared folder between VM and Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install VBoxGuestAdditions manually! Start your virtual machine, open a terminal and type in this order those commands:

```
sudo apt-get install wget
wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.8/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.4.iso
sudo mkdir /media/VBoxGuestAdditions
sudo mount -o loop VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.4.iso /media/VBoxGuestAdditions
sudo sh /media/VBoxGuestAdditions/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
rm VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.4.iso
sudo umount /media/VBoxGuestAdditions
sudo rmdir /media/VBoxGuestAdditions
```

it may ask your root password, if your user does not belong to sudoers, just type `su -`, insert root psswd and repeat all above command without sudo:

```
apt-get install wget
wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.8/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.4.iso
mkdir /media/VBoxGuestAdditions
mount -o loop VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.4.iso /media/VBoxGuestAdditions
sh /media/VBoxGuestAdditions/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
rm VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.4.iso
umount /media/VBoxGuestAdditions
rmdir /media/VBoxGuestAdditions
```

You just have to reboot now and you should be able to see you shared folder!